# Call to UpdateListItems not updating items?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-services

I have the following code:

```
XmlNode newItemRes = ceoList.GetListItems("Pages", null, getItem, ndViewFields, null, null, null);
XDocument d = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(newItemRes));
XNamespace ns = "#RowsetSchema";
string newItemId = (from x in d.Descendants(ns + "row")
                 orderby x.Attribute("ows_Created_x0020_Date")
                 select (string)x.Attribute("ows_ID")).First();

newFolderXml = String.Format(
                        @"<Batch OnError='Continue'>
                            <Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>
                                <Field Name='ID'>" + newItemId + @"</Field>
                                <Field Name='PublishingPageContent'>{0}</Field>
                                <Field Name='Title'>{1}</Field>
                                <Field Name='TaxKeywordTaxHTField'>28;Friday Memo|938edce3-67fd-438e-9c45-f475ab846187</Field>
                            </Method>
                        </Batch>", 
                                 SPEncode.HtmlEncode(String.Format(htmlBase, title, quickLinks, newPageContent)),
                                 "Friday Memo for " + nextFriday.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));

xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml(newFolderXml);
newItem = xd.DocumentElement;
createdItem = ceoList.UpdateListItems("Pages", newItem);
```

When I look at the value in `newItemId` it is the ID of the list item I need to update, but for some reason after I execute this code the page is not updated.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
bool test = ceoList.CheckOutFile("http://sp-pubdev:88/" + newUrl, "false", "");
```

before the code above (I was using `true` fore the second parameter before) fixed this issue.